# Should the class diagram represent a specific framework?

Tags: oop, architecture, frameworks, uml, software-design

I know that frameworks provide useful interfaces and classes that save a lot of time in implementation phase, so my question is:

- Should the framework interfaces and classes be included in my project's class
  diagram design or not?

and if it is,

- Does this affect the reusability of the design if I decided to change
  the framework in the future?

Comment: What is "my class diagram"? Your personal poster above your desk?

Comment: @ThomasKilian I mean my project's class diagram, thank you edited ^^

Comment: Still, who is the reader of it?

Comment: Strange you're asking a UML question and removing the tag for it. That will likely not help yourself.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Do you mean that it should be included to guarantee that the implementation structure is the the same as the design? but does that mean that I should decide on a framework before drawing my class diagram?

Comment: Include as much information as the target audience needs to understand (and make technical decisions based on) the diagram. If the reader is fluent in the framework in question, you may only need to include e.g. the names of the directly related modules. If they don't, you'll need to fill in whatever necessary knowledge they lack.

Comment: If you answer my question on who will be the audience of your UML model I can eventually give an answer.

Comment: @Jordan Thank you

Comment: @ThomasKilian Okey I apologize. Developers, testers, the client I guess if he has a technical background. Any one who needs to understand the system and the relationships between classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML diagrams are intended to be read by different interest groups. Business likes to see requirements, use cases and activities. Architects/testers need that as a basis to develop/test the system. And the results produced by the architects (static and behavioral class diagrams) are meant to be read by programmers. Each reader group has a focus on certain parts but will eventually peek more or less into border areas (from their perspective).

So to answer your question: yes, frameworks shall be part of the model. Architects should pay attention as to how to cut the system. Frameworks should be designed with a different (broader) scope. So eventually you have frameworks that will be used only partially in a system. Or a system has a potential for a framework and it will be designed to be easily decoupled. Of course, this is a tricky task and architects need lots of experience to fulfill all the needs that come from business and eventually other stakeholders.

Answer (score -2):

No, theoretically it shouldn't, but you're also free to do so.

As stated by the authors of UML: [Rumbaugh, Jacobson, Booch](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=294049)
on **The Unified Modeling Language Reference Manual** at page 25

> **Across implementation languages and platforms**. The UML is intended to be usable for systems implemented in various implementation languages and platforms, including programming languages, databases, 4GLs, organization documents, firmware, and so on. The front-end work should be identical or similar in all cases, while the back-end work will differ somewhat for each medium.